# How to send recovery mails from our domain address (mine@xxtech.com) to any user email using JavaMail API

Tags: java, jakarta-mail

I want to make code which can send recovery password by usibg javaMail API to send from  my official Domain address like abc@xyz.com.

i went some coding like using smtp.gmail.com

THIS
   [BLOG](http://www.mkyong.com/java/javamail-api-sending-email-via-gmail-smtp-example/)  i referred  to send mail to any user email address.

```
this structure i want:

 from : deepu@exxxxtechnology.com-----( not deepu@gmail.com  )
 to: anyuser@anydomain.com, user@gmail.com / user@hotmail.com /user@yahoomail.com

 is it possible ?
```

Comment: You need to get smtp information(host/port) for exxxxtechnology.com (your company) from your IT guys and need to put there in your code. It will work same as gmail.

Comment: what are you asking how to send a mail using JAVA MAIL API , or you are having any other prob ??

Comment: i am asking , how to send mail to specific domain address by taking emails as inputs

Answer (score 1):

```
/*
 * EMailSender.java
 *
 */
package com.projectName.mail;

import javax.mail.*;
import javax.mail.internet.InternetAddress;
import javax.mail.internet.MimeMessage;

import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.security.Security;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.util.Properties;

public class EMailSender {

private final static String SMTP_HOST_NAME = "smtp_host_name";
private final static String SMTP_AUTH = "smtp_auth";
private final static String DEBUG = "debug";
private final static String SMTP_PORT = "smtp_port";
private final static String SMTP_SOCKETFACTORY_PORT = "smtp_socketfactory_port";
private final static String SMTP_SOCKETFACTORY_CLASS = "smtp_socketfactory_class";
private final static String SMTP_SOCKETFACTORY_FALLBACK = "smtp_socketfactory_fallback";
private final static String EMAIL_SENDER = "email_sender";
private final static String EMAIL_SENDER_PASSWORD = "email_sender_password";
private Properties _emailproperties = null;

/** Creates a new instance of GoogleMailSender */
public EMailSender(Properties emailProperties) {
    _emailproperties = emailProperties;
    Security.addProvider(new com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.Provider());
}

/**
 * Sends email using SSL protocol.
 * 
 * @param recipient
 *            The mail address of the recipient. Recipient is the person who
 *            will receive the mail.
 * @param subject
 *            The subject of the mail.
 * @param message
 *            The content of the message.
 * @throws MessagingException
 *             Problem during sending message.
 */
public void sendSSLMessageAuthenticated(String recipient, String subject, String message)
        throws MessagingException {
    Properties props = new Properties();
    props.put("mail.smtp.host", _emailproperties
            .getProperty(SMTP_HOST_NAME));
    props.put("mail.smtp.auth", _emailproperties.getProperty(SMTP_AUTH,
            "true"));
    props.put("mail.debug", _emailproperties.getProperty(DEBUG, "false"));
    props.put("mail.smtp.port", _emailproperties.getProperty(SMTP_PORT));
    props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.port", _emailproperties
            .getProperty(SMTP_SOCKETFACTORY_PORT));
    props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.class", _emailproperties
            .getProperty(SMTP_SOCKETFACTORY_CLASS));
    props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.fallback", _emailproperties
            .getProperty(SMTP_SOCKETFACTORY_FALLBACK, "false"));

    // props.setProperty("proxySet", "true");
    // props.setProperty("http.proxyHost", "111.111.111.111");
    // props.setProperty("http.proxyPort", "81");

    final String sender = _emailproperties.getProperty(EMAIL_SENDER);
    final String password = _emailproperties.getProperty(
            EMAIL_SENDER_PASSWORD, "");

    Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(props,
            new javax.mail.Authenticator() {

                protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
                    return new PasswordAuthentication(sender, password);
                }
            });

    Message msg = new MimeMessage(session);
    InternetAddress addressFrom = new InternetAddress(sender);
    msg.setFrom(addressFrom);

    InternetAddress addressTo = new InternetAddress(recipient);
    msg.setRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO, addressTo);
    msg.setSubject(subject);
    msg.setContent(message, "text/plain");
    Transport.send(msg);
}

/**
 * Sends email using SSL protocol.
 * 
 * @param recipient
 *            The mail address of the recipient. Recipient is the person who
 *            will receive the mail.
 * @param subject
 *            The subject of the mail.
 * @param message
 *            The content of the message.
 * @throws MessagingException
 *             Problem during sending message.
 */
public void sendMessageUnauthenticated(String recipient, String subject,
        String message) throws MessagingException {
    Properties props = new Properties();
    props.put("mail.smtp.host", _emailproperties
            .getProperty(SMTP_HOST_NAME));
    props.put("mail.smtp.auth", _emailproperties.getProperty(SMTP_AUTH,
            "false"));
    props.put("mail.debug", _emailproperties.getProperty(DEBUG, "false"));
    props.put("mail.smtp.port", _emailproperties.getProperty(SMTP_PORT));

    final String sender = _emailproperties.getProperty(EMAIL_SENDER);

    Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(props, null);

    Message msg = new MimeMessage(session);
    InternetAddress addressFrom = new InternetAddress(sender);
    msg.setFrom(addressFrom);

    InternetAddress addressTo = new InternetAddress(recipient);
    msg.setRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO, addressTo);
    msg.setSubject(subject);
    msg.setContent(message, "text/plain");
    Transport.send(msg);
}

/**
 * test the function(including {@codeutil.portal} in {@codeutil.test} caused
 * some problems so test is done via the main method)
 * 
 * @param args
 * @throws IOException
 * @throws MessagingException
 * @throws SQLException
 */
public static void main(final String args[]) throws IOException,
        MessagingException {
    EMailSender _emailSender = null;
    Properties portalProperties = new Properties();
    FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(
            "C:\\project_home\\mail.properties");
    portalProperties.load(fis);
    fis.close();
    _emailSender = new EMailSender(portalProperties);
    _emailSender.sendMessageUnauthenticated("test@gmail.com",
            "Test!", "Send by TestEmailSender!");
}
```

}

fill the properties file or make it hardcoded.

Comment: Note that the code above is full of [common JavaMail mistakes](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail/faq/index.html#commonmistakes).

Answer (score 0):

For that you need server security certificate for your smtp server, which you'll need to purchase or acquire somewhere.

Comment: Please explain why a CA issued server certificate is required?